# XPath get child nodes based on value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following input

```
     <LOV_List>
            <LOV>

                <DisplayValue>...</DisplayValue>
                <Code>15</Code>

            </LOV>
            <LOV>
                <DisplayValue>...</DisplayValue>
                <Code>15</Code>
            </LOV>

                       ...

      <LOV_List>
```

I'm trying to get the following output

```
      <List>
            <values>
                <Id>1</Id>
                <DisplayValue1>...</DisplayValue1>
                <DisplayValue2>..</DisplayValue2>
            <values>
    </List>
```

But in order to get it I need to compare the `<Code>` values. If the value is the same than I need to return the `DisplayValues` of the nodes. 
I'm new at this so please give me pointers how to proceed.

Comment: Where does the `<Id>1</Id>` come from, the `Code` you want to compare is `15` in the sample? As for pointers on learning XSLT and XPath, there are books and tutorials, some even available for free, like https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm, so take your time reading and learning and trying to apply what you have learned.

Comment: The <Id> is self generated. It simply states some kind of order. I need help with how to compare nodes without knowing their value beforehand.

Comment: @banb Which version of XSLT are you using? This looks like a grouping question and the solution differs in XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0.

Comment: I'm using xslt 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of grouping and since you are using XSLT 1.0, you will have to use [muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to get the required output.

Define a key to group the elements using the value of  `Code`.

```
<xsl:key name="kCode" match="LOV" use="Code" />
```

Match the grouped elements using their ids and the key.

```
<xsl:template match="LOV[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kCode', Code)[1])]">
    <values>
        <Id><xsl:number format="1" /></Id>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('kCode', Code)">
            <DisplayValue>
                <xsl:value-of select="DisplayValue" />
            </DisplayValue>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </values>
</xsl:template>
```

The complete XSLT is as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" > 
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="kCode" match="LOV" use="Code" />

    <xsl:template match="LOV_List">
        <List>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </List>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="LOV[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kCode', Code)[1])]">
        <values>
            <Id><xsl:number format="1" /></Id>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('kCode', Code)">
                <xsl:copy-of select="DisplayValue" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </values>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="LOV" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<List>
    <values>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <DisplayValue>..</DisplayValue>
        <DisplayValue>....</DisplayValue>
    </values>
</List>
```